# Query remains in table when i clear the search box

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

When I clear the search box in the form, the table shows the same info (I want the table to show the original one, without any query).

Code:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If TextBox14.Text = "" Then
        Call NotFound()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CustomerInfo1BindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "')" &
            "OR (CustomerName LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "') OR (CustomerNumber LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "')" &
            "OR (OrderDate LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "')"
        If CustomerInfo1BindingSource.Count <> 0 Then
            With CustomerInfo1DataGridView
                .DataSource = CustomerInfo1BindingSource
            End With

        Else
            MsgBox("Not Found!")
            CustomerInfoBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've read the question correctly it appears that you're saying this:

1. You add a search term to `TextBox14` which is then applied to the `CustomerInfo1BindingSource.Filter` and in turn that filters `CustomerInfo1DataGridView` as expected
2. You remove the search term from `TextBox14` and click the button again
3. The filtered `CustomerInfo1DataGridView` remains untouched rather than showing everything

If that is the case I can see that code flow isn't exactly what you're expecting. Change it to be something like:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    If TextBox14.Text = "" Then
        CustomerInfoBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
        MsgBox("Not Found!")
    Else
        CustomerInfo1BindingSource.Filter = "(Convert(ID, 'System.String') LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "')" &
            "OR (CustomerName LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "') OR (CustomerNumber LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "')" &
            "OR (OrderDate LIKE '" & TextBox14.Text & "')"
        If CustomerInfo1BindingSource.Count <> 0 Then
            With CustomerInfo1DataGridView
                .DataSource = CustomerInfo1BindingSource
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As it stands with your code the line`CustomerInfoBindingSource.Filter = Nothing` is not being hit because there is no search term in `TextBox14`. Instead it's calling this `NotFound()` method which we don't have visibility of, and then exiting the method.

It might be worth also reading up on the official documentation. You can call [RemoveFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.removefilter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) on a `BindingSource`:

```
CustomerInfoBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
```